# Looking for Permutations of Options algorithm in Javascript. Maybe…?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, permutation, combinatorics

I’m not sure what to call this sort of problem, and thus I can’t find solid examples of it. I am writing in JS, but a pseudocode algorithm is a fine solution.

Say there is a basket of 3 goods I want. The basket contains toothpaste, a toothbrush, and baking soda. I have three possible vendors to choose from, and I can choose each item from a different vendor.

I store the price data in a 2d array, like this:

```
productVendors = [
    [3,6,2],
    [9,4,5],
    [1,3,4]
];
```

Where each row is a different vendor, and each column is a specific product. `col1 = toothpaste`, `col2 = toothbrush`, `col3 = baking soda`, e.g.

`productVendors[0][0] = 3` which stands for the first vendor’s price for toothpaste.

I need an algorithm that returns every possible basket of *n* specific goods, from *n* vendors. The resulting baskets would have the coordinates for each item in it, not the price, Like so:

```
           //item1   //item2    //item3
basket1 = [{x:0,y:0}, {x:1,y:1}, {x:2,y:2}];
basket2 = [{x:2,y:0}, {x:0,y:1}, {x:1,y:2}];
…

allBaskets = [basket1, basket2, basket3, etc…];
```

This java forum has an almost identical problem being solved, but I do not understand it.

**Algorithm:**
https://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/81134-optimise-recursive-method-prints-all-possible-rows-2d-array.html#post351752

**Example of use:**
https://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/81134-optimise-recursive-method-prints-all-possible-rows-2d-array.html#post351876

I would like to understand a solution completely, not only have something that works. First time asking a question here, so thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: *"I can choose each item from a different vendor"* : you *can*, or you *must* -- so that no two products in the same basket come from the same vendor?

Comment: Can. Not a necessity.

Comment: Could you explain what x and y mean in your example? Which one is the row number / vendor number? Is it coincidence that y is always going from 0 to 2 in the example output? Also, is the order of items in the basket of any importance so that the algorithm should also produce all orderings of the same vendor-item combinations?

Comment: @trincot ´x´ is vendor number/row number. The ´y´ is the product number/column number. Value of ´y´ will always be in order from 0 – numberOfProducts. The value for ´x´ will (out of necessity) be in a different order for every basket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output seems to have objects with 3 variable components which can take *n* values:

- the position in the basket array,
- the x-coordinate, and
- the y-coordinate

In comments you explained that you expect *n<sup>n</sup>* solutions, so this means one of the 3 components is duplicate. It seems the y-coordinate and the index in the desired result are those duplicates: in your example they are always the same.

#### All *n<sup>n</sup>* permutations with repetitions

This comes down to producing all possible lists of size *n* that can be made with *n* values, duplicates allowed. All items must be in a basket, and only once each, but not all vendors must be represented by them: there might be two or more items in the basket that come from the same vendor.

You can use a recursive algorithm for that. At each level of recursion we determine the vendor for one particular item. All possible vendors are iterated for it. For each of those, a recursive call is made to do the same for all following items, so generating all possibilities:

```js
    function* permutations(n) {
        // Produce array [0, ..., n-1]
        const arr = [...Array(n).keys()];

        function* generate(n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                yield [...arr]; // a copy of arr
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    arr[n] = i;
                    yield* generate(n - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        yield* generate(n - 1);
    }

// Sample call for n=4
for (let arr of permutations(4)) {
    // output permuted arrays as x-y pairs:
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.map( (x, y) => ({ x, y }))));
    // For normal permutation view (without y), replace above line with following:
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The above implementation uses some ES6 features, such as the spread syntax (to get an array copy of an iterable), destructuring (for the swap), and generators. The generator (`function*`) returns an iterator which provides the permutations as they are yielded.

In my first version of this answer I had understood that there could not be duplicate vendors in one basket. That leads to a pure permutation problem:

#### All *n!* permutations without repetitions

If all vendors must be represented in each basket, then this becomes a plain permutations problem.

For generating permutations there are several efficient algorithms, such as [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm):

```js
function* permutations(n) {
    // Produce array [0, ..., n-1]
    const arr = [...Array(n).keys()];
    
    function swap(i, j) {
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
    }

    function* generate(n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            yield [...arr]; // a copy of arr
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                yield* generate(n - 1);
                swap(n%2 ? 0 : i, n - 1);
            }
            yield* generate(n - 1);
        }
    }

    yield* generate(n);
}

// Sample call for n=4
for (let arr of permutations(4)) {
    // output permuted arrays as x-y pairs:
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.map( (x, y) => ({ x, y }))));
    // For normal permutation view (without y), replace above line with following:
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Heap's algorithm is quite obscure, but he found a pattern to select an element to swap with the last element to produce the next set of permutations via recursion:

1. Use recursion to generate the *(n-1)!* permutations of the first *n-1* elements, appending the last element to each of these *n-1*-size permutations. This will generate all of the *n*-size permutations that end with the last element.
2. If *n* is odd, take the first element, and else the *i<sup>th</sup>* element, and swap it with the last element.
3. Repeat the first two steps for *i* ranging between 0 and *n-2*, and execute step 1 one more time.

In step 2 it may seem that always the same two values are swapped back and forth (as *n* does not change in the loop), but then notice that the first step alters the order in the array, so what *was* the first element's value, no longer is (in general) *after* step 1.

In fact, in each execution of step 1, the last element will be different, so after completion of the loop all permutations will have been generated.

The recursion ends when there is only one element to consider in the array. In that case nothing needs to swap, and the array is output in its current ordering (via a `yield`).

Note that there are several faulty variants of this algorithm out there, and variants that use 1-based indexing, so it can become quite confusing when comparing those variants.

Comment: Now, I believe this is addressing a different permutation problem. I’m not actually looking to swap order of values, since the item’s identity is dependent on its location in the 2d array. There are 256 options for a 4x4 array. 4^4. Not looking for normal permutations of values.

Comment: OK, so you are looking for permutations *with repetitions*. I added a solution for that in my answer (it is the first), leaving my previous answer (permutations without repetitions) in a second section.

Comment: Your newest answer is exactly what I was looking for. :) I am new to Javascript, so I’ll be researching the keywords and techniques you used! Thank you for your patience and helpfulness.

Comment: By the way, yes, the ´y´ value is redundant, though having it is conducive to a specific problem I had in mind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are *n* vendors and *n* goods I consider that each item should come from different vendor. This can be done as follows:

1. have a recursive function gen(n, arr), where arr is partly generated basket
2. if *arr.length* is equal to *n* - push *arr* to baskets list and return from function
3. inside of function you should iterate over each item id *(i)* and if *arr* doesn't contain it - go to gen(n, [...arr, {x: arr.length, y: i}]). This will add a pair which represents item which you take from next vendor (vendor with id arr.length)
4. To check if id is already in you can do as follows: `arr.filter(item => (item.y == id)).length > 0`